# Unable to start tomcat server with service start

Tags: ubuntu, apt, tomcat

I installed tomcat on ubuntu using the command:  `sudo apt install tomcat9`
But I am unable to run it with any command like `sudo service tomcat start`
`sudo service tomcat9 start` It gives an error `tomcat9: unrecognized service`
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo systemctl start tomcat9`?

Comment: I get this message - `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`  I am using WSL2 ubuntu inside windows-10

Comment: You didn't say you were using WSL. Everything's different there. I've suggested an edit to your question that incorporates this new information.